# How do I make my transform values match up to the ones on the Object Properties window?

Tags: modeling, vertices, transforms, transform-orientation

Whenever I transform something in Blender 2.8, there is a little transform box that shows up; but the values in there don't match up with the values in the Object Properties Window at the right. I would prefer to make both the same so the values are consistent for both. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: please use images so that others understand what window you are talking about. Is this in edit mode?

Answer (score 1):

The pop up shows the transform relative to starting position. The object properties shows absolute position, relative to grid. If you want to change absolute position, just use the object properties panel and type in the values you are after.

Comment: To clarify this somewhat.  Object properties (let's forget about constraints for now) show transforms relative to parent. What we would cal _local_ space.  With no parent object properties would match for  both _local_ and  _global_ space.  The 3d cursor is  in _global_ space.  Can transform using either space.